# how to highlighted clicked taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am using below code :

```
 echo "<h1>".Volume."</h1>";
$tid=db_query("SELECT th.tid FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy th 
INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_data td ON th.tid=td.tid
INNER JOIN field_data_field_books book ON book.field_books_tid = th.tid
WHERE td.vid = '6' AND th.parent = '0'  AND book.entity_id = $nid
")->FetchField();
print $tid->Name;

$child=taxonomy_get_children($tid);
 foreach($child as $t){

$url = "taxonomy/term/$t->name";
    print '<a href="'.$url.'">'.ucwords($t->name).'</a><br>';


    }
```

they show volume 1,volume 2,volume 3 and they have linked problem is that when i am click on volume 1 they highlighted and show no link but other volumes are show linked in normal form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only advise to use the available API functions.

To build the link use the [l](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) function:

```
$link = l(ucwords($t->name), 'taxonomy/term/' . $t->tid);
```

You can also pass in an options array, so to add an active class to the link when the link url points to the current page, you could use something like this:

```
$options = array();
if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && arg(2) == $t->tid) {
    $options = array('attributes' => array('class' => 'active'));
}
$link = l(ucwords($t->name), 'taxonomy/term/' . $t->tid, $options);
```

Also, this kind of code shouldn't be mixed directly in a template, especially not the database query. Have a look at the answers to this question for more insight: [Preprocess functions and template files](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75168/preprocess-functions-and-template-files)

Comment: i don`t have a FTP access just i have site login access i am applying this code they give PDO object error

Comment: @user25762 Where or how do you add the code?

Comment: `$tid=db_query("SELECT th.tid FROM taxonomy_term_hierarchy th 
INNER JOIN taxonomy_term_data td ON th.tid=td.tid
INNER JOIN field_data_field_books book ON book.field_books_tid = th.tid
WHERE td.vid = '6' AND th.parent = '0'  AND book.entity_id = $nid
")->FetchField();
print $tid->Name;

$child=taxonomy_get_children($tid);
 foreach($child as $t){
  $options = array();
if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && arg(2) == $t->tid) {
    $options = array('attributes' => array('class' => 'active'));
};
  $link = l($t->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $t->nid,$options)."<br>";
print $link;


 }`

Comment: @user25762 Please refrain from posting unasked code and instead reply to the questions. What you just posted doesn't help at all.

Comment: i am using your code in the foreach loop and its declare in l function same code use as you given

Comment: @user25762 But where is that foreach loop? As I understand you it, don't edit files via FTP, so where do you add the code?

Comment: i am using this code in blocks

Comment: @user25762 Ok, now we're getting somewhere ;) Really, you shouldn't do this kind of stuff in Blocks. It will just give you a lot of headaches on the long run. If your client can't give you at least FTP access, don't accept the work! Regarding the PDO error: From your question I understood, that the query itself worked. My suggestions where only about the link generation and the added active class. If the query doesn't work, please post a new question. It will be easier there to give you assistance, otherwise this comment thread will turn into a discussion, and that's not how this works here.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but our query work perfectly